# Xcode 9: How can I set the action event of an IBAction

Tags: xcode, events, storyboard, xcode9, ibaction

I'd like to change the action event of a button in a storyboard in Xcode 9. In Xcode 8, when control clicking and dragging a button to the code, there was a way to set the action event. In Xcode 9, this selection is missing. Was this setting removed or can I find it somewhere else?

Thanks in advance.

In Xcode 9:

[image: action setting popup in Xcode 9]

In Xcode 8:

[image: action setting popup in Xcode 8]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSButton` **does not differentiate between events** in the same way `UIButton` does. Your example picture for Xcode 8 shows the popup that comes up after connecting a `UIButton`.

If you want to invoke the IBAction for multiple events, you can use [`sendAction(on:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontrol/1428972-sendaction).